# Spring @scheduled cron expression for every 1st Monday of the month

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, cron, scheduled-tasks

I'm trying to have my code execute on a fixed schedule, based on a Spring cron expression. I would like the code to be executed on every first Monday of the Month at 10:00 am.

```
           @Scheduled(cron = "")
           public void sendEmail() {
           // ...
           }
```

When I write:

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0 12 ? * MON#1")
protected synchronized void execute() {...}
```

Application prints following error on startup:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Encountered invalid @Scheduled method 'execute': For input string: "1#1"
    at org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.processScheduled(ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:461) ~[spring-context-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessAfterInitialization(ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331) ~[spring-context-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:423) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1633) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 7):

I have answered a similar question here
[How to fire the job on first monday of month using cron expresssion in spring @Scheduled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51669973/how-to-fire-the-job-on-first-monday-of-month-using-cron-expresssion-in-spring-s/51670629#51670629)

The pattern is a list of six single space-separated fields: representing second, minute, hour, day, month, weekday. Month and weekday names can be given as the first three letters of the English names.
https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/support/CronSequenceGenerator.html

You can use this expression for that. There is only one Monday in the first 7 days of a month.

```
"0 0 10 1-7 * MON"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
0 0 10 ? * 2#1
```

- 0 -> 0th second \
- 0 -> 0th minute |-> 10:00am
- 10 -> 10th hour /
- 2#1 -> 1st Monday of each month

Comment: Why 2 is monday?

Comment: Can you explain this format? what is 2 means? in 2#1 ?

Comment: Also it doesn't work in spring  **Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Encountered invalid @Scheduled method 'execute': For input string: "2#1"**

Answer (score 0):

You can use this expression

```
 @Scheduled(cron = "0 0 10 ? 1/1 MON#1 *")
```

Answer (score 0):

@Scheduled(cron = "0 0 7 1-7 * MON")

Comment: Please add some more explanation or a link to documentation.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, Spring schedule does not support full unix-style cron format.

[CronSequenceGenerator](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/support/CronSequenceGenerator.html)

In your case, you can try to switch to Quartz instead of innate scheduling.

Your Trigger should be configured to run with the cron expression: `0 0 10 ? * 2#1`

```
Trigger trigger = TriggerBuilder
    .newTrigger()
    .withIdentity("triggerIdentity")
    .withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule("0 0 10 ? * 2#1"))
    .build();
```

Comment: Thx for sharing another way but I prefer declarative style