# Cron expression for 1st and 3rd Sundays for @Scheduled

Tags: java, spring, cron

I know how I can schedule a job for first Sunday of the months thanks to answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51680910/926572).

`"0 0 10 1-7 * SUN"`

But I want to trigger the job on first & third Sundays.

Also can it be a one liner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to follow the same pattern then

So as 1 st Sunday will always be in day 1 to 7 and likewise 2nd Sunday 8-14 and 3rd Sunday 15-21 and 4th one 22-28

```
"0 0 10 1-7 * SUN"
"0 0 10 15-21 * SUN"
```

**or**

```
"0 0 10 1-7,15-21 * SUN"
```

Answer (score 1):

From the crontab man page "     Note: The day of a command's execution can be specified in the following two fields — 'day of month', and 'day of week'.  If both fields are restricted (i.e., do not contain the "*" character), the command will be run when either field  matches  the  current
time.  For example,
"30 4 1,15 * 5" would cause a command to be run at 4:30 am on the 1st and 15th of each month, plus every Friday." so the above answer will not do what you want.